# How to broadcast pandas series with different indices?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas series, each with a different index:

```
In [2]: a = pd.Series(range(5), index=pd.Index(list('abcde'), name='index'))
In [3]: b = pd.Series(range(4), index=pd.Index(list('ABCD'), name='BIG_INDEX'))
```

What I would like to do is something along the lines of `a.mul(b, axis=1)` to instruct pandas to broadcast b along the 1 axis before performing a ufunc (e.g. multiply, raise to the power of, etc). Is there a better way of doing this than using apply?

```
In [4]: a.apply(lambda x: x*b)
Out[4]:
BIG_INDEX  A  B  C   D
index
a          0  0  0   0
b          0  1  2   3
c          0  2  4   6
d          0  3  6   9
e          0  4  8  12
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`numpy.outer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) to perform the calculation as if `a` and `b` were arrays:

```
In [285]: pd.DataFrame(np.outer(a, b), columns=b.index, index=a.index)
Out[285]: 
BIG_INDEX  A  B  C   D
index                 
a          0  0  0   0
b          0  1  2   3
c          0  2  4   6
d          0  3  6   9
e          0  4  8  12
```

This is quicker than calling `a.apply(lambda x: x*b)`.

---

By the way, all NumPy ufuncs [come with 5 methods](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html): `outer`, `accumulate`, `reduce`, `reduceat`, and `at`. So another way to write the solution above is

```
In [34]: pd.DataFrame(np.multiply.outer(a, b), columns=b.index, index=a.index)
Out[36]: 
BIG_INDEX  A  B  C   D
index                 
a          0  0  0   0
b          0  1  2   3
c          0  2  4   6
d          0  3  6   9
e          0  4  8  12
```

And when written this way, it is clear how to apply the same idea to any NumPy ufunc. For example, to make and addition table out of `a` and `b`, call `np.add`'s `outer` method:

```
In [37]: pd.DataFrame(np.add.outer(a, b), columns=b.index, index=a.index)
Out[37]: 
BIG_INDEX  A  B  C  D
index                
a          0  1  2  3
b          1  2  3  4
c          2  3  4  5
d          3  4  5  6
e          4  5  6  7
```

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't super clear. I would like to know if there is a general solution for this problem, especially for all the two-argument ufuncs (e.g. mul, div, add, sub, pow, etc). Essentially, the problem is that when doing calculations with to numpy matrices, say a (4x1) matrix and a (1x5) matrix, you can do these operations and the broadcasting is handled automatically. But with series, say of sizes (4,) and (5,), you can't handle the mismatch without first converting the values into a numpy format. Any way around this?

Comment: Generally, Pandas operations try to **align** on the NDFrame's indices. In the operations you are contemplating (such as the one above) you want to ignore the Series index, and broadcast the *values* as you would with NumPy. That's not what Pandas is for. Whenever you want to treat the data as an indexless array, use NumPy not Pandas.

Comment: Well I don't really want to ignore the indices... I want to maintain them while broadcasting along a new index. It seems like the best way is to use an abstraction of your method, though, e.g.: `outer_opr = lambda x, y, opr: pd.DataFrame(opr(x.values.reshape((len(x), 1)), y.values.reshape((1, len(y)))), index=x.index, columns=y.index)`

Comment: Oh! Did not know about the outer methods. That's perfect - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

These days, I would recommend using [xarray](https://xarray.pydata.org/)!

xarray is a pydata-supported library built for exactly this - doing N-dimensional operations including broadcasting (like numpy) using  labeled-indices (like pandas).

In this case:

```py
In [2]: a = pd.Series(range(5), index=pd.Index(list('abcde'), name='index'))

In [3]: b = pd.Series(range(4), index=pd.Index(list('ABCD'), name='BIG_INDEX'))

In [4]: arr_a = a.to_xarray()

In [5]: arr_b = b.to_xarray()

In [6]: res = arr_a * arr_b

In [7]: res
Out[7]: 
<xarray.DataArray (index: 5, BIG_INDEX: 4)>
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 0,  2,  4,  6],
       [ 0,  3,  6,  9],
       [ 0,  4,  8, 12]])
Coordinates:
  * index      (index) object 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e'
  * BIG_INDEX  (BIG_INDEX) object 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D'
```

The result is an xarray.DataArray with dimensions `('index', 'BIG_INDEX')` - xarray explicitly uses dimension names to know when an index should be aligned or broadcast. Since `index ≠ BIG_INDEX`, `arr_a * arr_b` results in a broadcasting operation.

You can convert the data back to pandas with with the `to_series` method, and then use pandas operators to reshape back to your desired result:

```py
In [8]: res.to_series().unstack('BIG_INDEX')
Out[8]: 
BIG_INDEX  A  B  C   D
index                 
a          0  0  0   0
b          0  1  2   3
c          0  2  4   6
d          0  3  6   9
e          0  4  8  12
```

See the xarray docs on [computation: broadcasting by dimension name](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/v0.9.0/computation.html#broadcasting-by-dimension-name) for more information.